# Glassfishでクライアント証明書認証ができない

Tags: java, java8, openssl

下記URLを参考にGlassfishでクライアント証明書認証を実施しようとしたのですがサーバアクセス時にERR_CONNECTION_CLOSEDエラーが発生し、うまくいきません。

http://yoshio3.com/2010/02/08/glassfish-ssl%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC/

http://qiita.com/jabaraster/items/0343b12c593d534e5b2f

実施手順は以下です。GlassfishやOpenSSLの設定は全てデフォルトで行いました。

1. Glassfish管理画面でクライアント証明書認証を有効にする
2. binにdemoCAフォルダが作成される。
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>perl CA.pl -newca
3. クライアント証明書の秘密鍵を作成
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>openssl genrsa -des3 -out .¥client-private-key 2048
4. CSR作成
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>openssl req -new -days 365 -key .¥client-private-key
   -out .¥clientcsr.pem
5. CAにクライアント証明書を署名してもらう
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>openssl ca -config .¥openssl.cfg -in .¥clientcsr.pem
   -out .¥signed-clientcert.pem
6. x509形式に変換
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>openssl x509 -in .¥signed-clientcert.pem -out .¥sign
   ed-clientcert.x509
7. Glassfishに証明書をインポート
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>keytool -import -alias satou -file ¥glassf
   ish4¥glassfish¥domains¥domain1¥config¥cacerts.jks
8. ブラウザインポート用p12ファイル作成
   C:¥OpenSSL-Win64¥bin>openssl pkcs12 -export -in .¥signed-clientcert.pem -
   inkey .¥client-private-key -certfile demoCA¥cacert.pem -out .¥clientcert.p12
9. 証明書をブラウザにインストールし
   https://localhost:8282
   にアクセス

結果：ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

原因がわかる方回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 手順にサーバ証明書の発行がないように思われます。

Comment: @A-pZ Glassfishではデフォルトでサーバ証明書が発行されています。また、クライアント証明書認証にはサーバ証明書の発行は無関係であると思います。

Comment: クライアント証明書の提示確認だけでよいのですね、失礼しました。

手順7にて、Glassfishに証明書をインポートとありますが、記述しているコマンドの引数で情報がいくつか不足しているように思えます。

-alias satou はどの証明書でしょうか。
-glassfishの管理画面で、キーストアにしているファイル名は -fileにて指定しているcacerts.jksでしょうか。-fileに指定するのは証明書ファイルであり、証明書を保管するキーストアのファイル名を指定するのは -keystore です。